# Get external resource name using for_each in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am part of a team of developers using Terraform to provision some GCP resources. A developer on this team (not me) created two GCP Pub/Sub topics using the following Terraform file:

```
# dead_letter_topcs.tf
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "primary_dead_letter" {
  name = "primary-dead-letter"
  labels = {
      role  = "dead-letter"
      qname = "primary"
  }
  message_retention_duration = "1209600s"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "secondary_dead_letter" {
  name = "secondary-dead-letter"
  labels = {
      role  = "dead-letter"
      qname = "secondary"
  }
  message_retention_duration = "1209600s"
}
```

I am trying to create some subscriptions to these two topics in the following file:

```
# my_deadletter_subscriptions.tf
locals {
  queue_names = toset(["primary", "secondary"])
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "deadletter_gcs" {
  for_each = local.queue_names

  name  = "deadletter-gcs-${each.key}"
  topic = "google_pubsub_topic.${each.key}_dead_letter.name"      

  enable_message_ordering      = false
  enable_exactly_once_delivery = false

  cloud_storage_config {
   ... more ...
  }
}
```

However, when I get this error message:

> Error: Error creating Subscription: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid resource name given (name=projects/mygcpproject/topics/google_pubsub_topic.primary_dead_letter.name).
> Refer to https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-basics#resource_names for more information.

I realize I could just create two copies of the google_pubsub_subscription resource but I do not want to do that as I might need to add several more topics at a later date. How do I refer to the topic name using `queue_names` variables?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform does not support the interpolation you are trying to use. You could either (re)create the pubsub topic with `for_each` using the same variable as for subscription. For that, you would need to import the existing pubsub to the new resource. So for example:

```
locals {
  queue_names = toset(["primary", "secondary"])
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "dead_letter_queue" {
  for_each = local.queue_names
  name = "${each.key}-dead-letter"
  labels = {
      role  = "dead-letter"
      qname = each.key
  }
  message_retention_duration = "1209600s"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "deadletter_gcs" {
  for_each = local.queue_names

  name  = "deadletter-gcs-${each.key}"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.dead_letter_queue[each.key].name

  enable_message_ordering      = false
  enable_exactly_once_delivery = false

  cloud_storage_config {
   ... more ...
  }
}
```

For that to work, you would need to import the existing primary and secondary resources into state:

```
import {
  id = "projects/{{project}}/topics/primary-dead-letter" # or whatever the name is, not familiar with GCP
  to = google_pubsub_topic.dead_letter_queue["primary"]
}

import {
  id = "projects/{{project}}/topics/secondary-dead-letter" # or whatever the name is, not familiar with GCP
  to = google_pubsub_topic.dead_letter_queue["secondary"]
}
```

More detailed explanation for imports can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import#examples).

The second way (more readable maybe) is to use [`for_each` chaining](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources):

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "dead_letter_queue" {
  for_each = toset(["primary", "secondary"])
  name = "${each.key}-dead-letter"
  labels = {
      role  = "dead-letter"
      qname = each.key
  }
  message_retention_duration = "1209600s"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "deadletter_gcs" {
  for_each = google_pubsub_topic.dead_letter_queue

  name  = "deadletter-gcs-${each.key}"
  topic = each.value.name

  enable_message_ordering      = false
  enable_exactly_once_delivery = false

  cloud_storage_config {
   ... more ...
  }
}
```

The import part would remain the same.

The last option is to reference the resource properly, i.e., `topic = google_pubsub_topic.primary_dead_letter.name` and have multiple resources.